# Transforming single QgsGeometry object from one CRS to another using PyQGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, line, geometry, coordinates

I have a polyline layer with roads in WGS84 that covers several UTM zones. For every road I need to place a set of points at different distances (in metres). To do so I want to reproject each road to respective UTM zone, create points in this UTM zone, reproject points to WGS84 and add them to respectful layer.

There is a `QgsCoordinateTransform()` class that allows to perform transformation for individual points, but it doesn't accept polylines. I guess I could manually disassemble polylines into the set of points, transform each of them and recreate a polyline, but I hope that there is a build-in method or class that I overlooked, that allows to transform individual polylines.

Comment: One option would be to convert your polyline to a polygon, then `transformPolygon()` that, then just take the outer ring again. Its pretty much just QVector operations all the way down...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`QgsGeometry.transform(QgsCoordinateTransform)`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a136798add705aaa3bce2b3fdd46463f4). For example after created your instance of `QgsCoordinateTransform` with source and dest crs, for each geometry instance do:

```py
sourceCrs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)
destCrs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2154)
tr = QgsCoordinateTransform(sourceCrs, destCrs, QgsProject.instance())
myGeometryInstance.transform(tr)
```

Documentation of the `QgsCoordinateTransform` class: https://qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateTransform.html#aa5ad428819ac020f8f5716e835ab754f

Beware that the transformation (applying `QgsCoordinateTransform`) will change the `QgsGeometry` instance.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The operation gives me back a 0 number and my geometry doesn't seems to be reprojected.

Comment: can you give more details abut what you did? e.g. wkt of the geom, origin and dest epsg code and all that can be usefl to replicate. Obviously also qgis version and platform. tnx

Comment: Ok I missed a step to get a QgsCoordinateSystemReference class in the choosen coordinate eg 2154. It still gave back a 0 but the vertex has changed their coordinate.

Comment: This codesnippet does not work anymore in QGIS 3.4.4 :
TypeError: QgsCoordinateTransform(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: too many arguments
  overload 2: not enough arguments
  overload 3: not enough arguments
  overload 4: not enough arguments
  overload 5: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem'

Comment: @Riccardo The API has changed and you need to add a third parameter QgsCoordinateTransformContext. You can get it from QgsProject.instance(). So the call should be like `QgsCoordinateTransform(crsSrc, crsDest, QgsProject.instance())`

Comment: tnx @spatialthoughts I've updated the post

Answer (score 12):

Old Question, but duckduckgo brings you here for "pyqgis transform single geometry"

Just like Riccardo Pointed out, the accepted answer does not work for scripts in QGIS 3, the situation is explained in the api reference:

> Python scripts should utilize the QgsProject.instance() project instance when creating QgsCoordinateTransform. This will ensure that any datum transforms defined in the project will be correctly respected during coordinate transforms. E.g.
>
> ```
> transform = QgsCoordinateTransform(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:3111"),
>                                    QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326"), QgsProject.instance())
> ```

Using QgsCoordinateTransform in QGIS 3 will transform the geometry instance inplace, and return 0:

```
geom = QgsGeometry(QgsPoint(5,20))
sourceCrs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)
destCrs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2154)
tr = QgsCoordinateTransform(sourceCrs, destCrs, QgsProject.instance())
geom.transform(tr)
#[out]: 0

geom
#[out]: <QgsGeometry: Point (930236.95432910311501473 3567516.9810206750407815)>

back_tr = QgsCoordinateTransform(destCrs, sourceCrs, QgsProject.instance())
geom.transform(back_tr)
#[out]: 0

geom
#[out]: <QgsGeometry: Point (5 19.99999999999911182)>
```

If you want to copy an already existing QgsGeometry Instance, the QgsGeometry class constructor will make the trick. From the docs:

> Class: QgsGeometry
>   class qgis.core.QgsGeometry
>   Bases: sip.wrapper
>
> Constructor
>
> QgsGeometry(QgsGeometry) Copy constructor will prompt a deep copy of the object

example:

```
geom2 = QgsGeometry(geom)
geom2
#[out]: <QgsGeometry: Point (5 19.99999999999911182)>
geom
#[out]: <QgsGeometry: Point (5 19.99999999999911182)>
geom2.transform(tr)
#[out]: 0
geom2
#[out]: <QgsGeometry: Point (930236.95432910579256713 3567516.98102056747302413)>
geom
#[out]: <QgsGeometry: Point (5 19.99999999999911182)>
```

Comment: OMG, using project as an argument for transformation looks like a terrible design to me...

Comment: I was just copying the docs there.

Comment: The reason for that is that the project might have defined specific transformation rules to be used for a specific transformation.