# Convert from EPSG 3857 to EPSG 4326 QGIS2.18

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, convert

I need to convert EPSG 3857 to EPSG 4326 in a plugin.

```
            #example EPSG 3857
            x = 5062443.00656
            y = -952576.546977
            #convert here to EPSG 4326
            #where x2 =41.3387949319,
            #where y2 = -8.55714071443
            return x2,y2 #return in EPSG 4326
```

something like the code above. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To convert with Qgis API you need to 2 class `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem` and `QgsCoordianteTransform` here them in action :

```
#example EPSG 3857
src_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(3857)
dest_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)
xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(src_crs, dest_crs)
x = 5062443.00656
y = -952576.546977
point = QgsPoint(x, y)
#convert here to EPSG 4326
pt_reproj = xform.transform(point)
#where x2 =41.3387949319,
#where y2 = -8.55714071443
#but mine return QgsPoint(45.4766992777683,-8.52550507570475)
return pt_reproj.x(),pt_reproj.y() #return in EPSG 4326
```

Comment: my x2 and y2 where wrong sorry. But this solution was exactly what i was looking for. Thank You

Comment: @JoséGabriel - Don't forget to accept SIGIS's answer by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side :)

Comment: @JoséGabriel Glad to help.

Answer (score 7):

- You could use [QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html) (as described in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163645/transforming-single-qgsgeometry-object-from-one-crs-to-another-using-pyqgis)):

  ```
  from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QgsCoordinateTransform, QgsPoint

  old_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(3857)
  new_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)
  tr = QgsCoordinateTransform(old_crs, new_crs)
  transform_points = tr.transform(QgsPoint(5062443.00656, -952576.546977))

  print transform_points
  >>> (45.4767,-8.52551)
  ```

---

- Or use the [osgeo.osr.SpatialReference class](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.osr.SpatialReference-class.html):

  ```
  from osgeo import osr

  old_crs = osr.SpatialReference() 
  old_crs.ImportFromEPSG(3857) 
  new_crs = osr.SpatialReference() 
  new_crs.ImportFromEPSG(4326) 
  transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(old_crs,new_crs) 
  transform_points = transform.TransformPoint(5062443.00656, -952576.546977)

  print transform_points[0], transform_points[1] 
  >>> 45.4766992778 -8.5255050757
  ```

---

Notice how in both cases, the `x` and `y` coordinates returned are `45.4766992778` and `-8.5255050757` respectively which differ slightly from those in your question.

Comment: You are every where ! Good to know for osgeo ! Very nice post. sorry for repeating same thing. We post almost at the same time. +1

Comment: @SIGIS - I don't think I post that often but thanks :). Also, your format is closer to the original posters so no need to apologise =)

Comment: my x2 and y2 where wrong sorry. Thank you to both.