# Reprojecting QgsPointXY

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I am writing a plugin to import some files into qgis. The files initially have coordinates in lat lon, but I want to reproject them to a local projection during the import.

So, I can set the CRS on the layer I am importing in and and I know that my imported points are in WGS 84, so what I want to do is similiar to what I would have done in postgis with

```
ST_Tranform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(15, 60),4326),32633);
```

to import the point into a layer WGS84 UTM zone33N

But in qgis, how can I make a PointXY() with a CRS and then reproject it to another CRS?

(I know I can read everything into a layer with CRS 4326 and then reproject the entire layer into a new layer, but I would prefer to do it without having to make an extra layer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following recipe

```py
# Create QgsGeometry from QgsPointXY
geom = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY (QgsPointXY(5,20))
# Prepare crs source and destination and instanciate a transform function
sourceCrs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)
destCrs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2154)
tr = QgsCoordinateTransform(sourceCrs, destCrs, QgsProject.instance())

# Option 1
# Clone (to not transform in place the geometry)
geom2 = QgsGeometry(geom)
geom2.transform(tr)
geom2.asPoint() # QgsPointXY

# Option 2, transform in place and avoid a copy. Better for your scenario
geom.transform(tr)
geom.asPoint() # QgsPointXY

# Option 3, Use the transform function to directly reproject QgsPointXY
# without intermediate QgsGeometry. Added due to your answer to compile solutions
tr.transform(QgsPointXY(5,20))
```

Sample adapted from [Transforming single QgsGeometry object from one CRS to another using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163645/transforming-single-qgsgeometry-object-from-one-crs-to-another-using-pyqgis) to fit your request

Comment: Great! The problem was to find the right level to do the tranformation on (i.e. the QgsGeometry object...)

Answer (score 5):

That is, for some reason, I ended up having to do

```
 point = QgsPointXY(float(lon), float(lat)) 
 point = tr.transform(point)
 geom = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(point)
```

Trying to do geom.transform(tr) did for some reason not work for me

Comment: Nice. Did not see that transform instance can be applied directly to a `QgsPointXY`

Comment: What is `prpoint`?

Comment: Typo, strange nobody has noticed earlier...