# Is it possible to define a projection for QgsPointXY()

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, pyqgis

I am creating a `QgsRectangle` like this:

```
llc = QgsPointXY(319660,4624088)       # lower left corner in UTM
urc = QgsPointXY(396425,4742843)       # upper right corner in UTM
aoi = QgsRectangle(llc,urc)
```

But how do I tell him the correct crs of these points? Can I pass the EPSG somehow?

Comment: IMHO it is not possible. The [`QgsPointXY`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsPointXY.html#qgis.core.QgsPointXY) class creates a point either from another point or from x,y coordinates. If you need you can reproject as shown here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349585/reprojecting-qgspointxy or here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/crs.html#crs-transformation

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way to define the extent in the raster calculator by Xmin, Xmax, Ymin and Ymax?  I use above defined aoi as extent: `QgsRasterCalculator('ras@1', output, 'GTiff', aoi, 15353, 23751, entries)`

Comment: Thank you Ben, I opened a new question to give full context and full code since the problem seems to be in a different part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You cannot pass an EPSG to `QgsPointXY`. None of the constructor methods of it allows to define a CRS. Also, you cannot set a CRS after creating a point.

In addition, a CRS cannot be defined for `QgsGeometry` and `QgsFeature`, too.